# VBA excel Disable/Enable Dropdown in IE

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I want to automate a website that each time the dropdown menu is already clickable, I can select the next button. It has 3 dropdown menus. When nothing is selected in the dropdown menus, it is clickable, however when a value is selected, the button will be disabled for a moment (time varies cause each time a value is selected there is a processing occurred in the back end side).

The source code of the button is like this:

> **When the page is idle or nothing is selected.**

```
<input name = "m_ct103$txtvalue" class="null" id="m_ct103_txtValue" style = "" type="text"/>
```

> **When a value is selected from the dropdown menu, the disabled property is visible.**

```
<input name = "m_ct104$txtvalue" class="null" disabled="disabled" id="m_ct104_txtValue" style = "" type="text"/>"
```

Comment: Is there a webpage we can test this with?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is only accessible for employees.

Comment: can you pastebin.com the page html?

Comment: From your above description, I understand that there are 3 dropdowns and 1 button. when nothing is selected button is available for click. when anything get selected it process something and button get disable until the process get finished. It is not clear that what you want to automate here. Try to develop a sample web page and try to post it here which can able to produce the issue. Also try to mention your overall requirement in detail. It can help us to understand the issue in better way. Thanks for your understanding.